# Grant Connect and Resource not working

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I'm trying to grant Connect and Resource in Oracle, and I get an error that says that the role do not exist:

```
SQL> grant connect to MY_SCHEMA;
grant connect to MY_SCHEMA
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01919: role 'CONNECT' does not exist
```

However, I check the roles and they exist:

```
SQL> select role from dba_roles;

ROLE
------------------------------
CONNECT
RESOURCE
```

Why I'm getting the error if both of the roles exist?

Comment: Login as SYS and try again. You must have proper privileges to grant a role.  Check documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9013.htm#i2094944 : `To grant a role, you must either have been granted the role with the ADMIN OPTION or have been granted the GRANT ANY ROLE system privilege, or you must have created the role.`